How to write a PHP Unit test against mysqli prepared statements?
I would like to write a PHP Unit test against a Class function.
Function:
        function ValidateToken(string $key, string $token): array {
            if (!empty($key) || !empty($token)) {
                $email = "%".htmlspecialchars($key)."%";
                $token = htmlspecialchars($token);
                $stmt = $this->c->prepare("SELECT expDate FROM `authuser` WHERE `reset_link_token`= ? AND `email1` LIKE ?");
                $stmt->bind_param('ss',$token,$email);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $curDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    if($row['expDate'] >= $curDate){
                        return array("response"=>1,"email"=>$key,"token"=>$token);
                    } else {
                        return array("response"=>2);
                    }
                } else {
                    return array("response"=>0);
                }
            } else {
                return array("response"=>0);
            }
        }

I would like to run a test against a successful, unexpired token. Here is my test that doesn't work:
    public function testExpiredTokenSuccess() {
        $successToken = new stdClass();
        $successToken->expDate = '2099-12-31 23:59:59'; // y2.1k bug
        $this->mockLF = array();

        $this->mockLF[0] = $successToken ;
        $this->dbMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Connection::class)    
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $curDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $this->authuserloginclass = new LoginFormClass();
        $returnVal = $this->authuserloginclass->ValidateToken('key','token');
        $this->assertEquals("1", $returnVal);
    }

The error reports that it fails to connect to the database. When this test runs, the database would be unavailable, so I need to mock certain things.
Does anything jump out as being the problem?

Do not use htmlspecialchars when doing DB operations. This function is only for when you display stuff in HTML

Would you be better off using a test database specifically for unit testing.  IMHO it provides a wider test than using mocking.

Don't mock the database, set it up and connect properly to a test database

Thanks @Dharman. These tests are run during a pipeline, so the database won't be available at that time.

But you can still add a database to the pipeline

I don't get it. How do you plan to test this function without a database? How it can be any logical?

At the very least, you can (and rather should) move lines 5-9 to another method which you would mock. So you will be able to test ValidateToken instead of "prepared statement". And also you must ditch lines 3 and 4 as they make no sense.

Since $this->c is what you want to mock for your test, how about you update the constructor of LoginFormClass so it accepts the connection object? That should simplify your test.
In the actual app logic, you can use some dependency injection library (e.g. PHP-DI) to help build the objects.
